# Add two DataTables to same excel worksheet in c#

Tags: c#, excel, datatables

I want to display two data tables one after another in the same excel worksheet in c#.I have tried like this.

```
var workBook = new XLWorkbook();
workBook.Worksheets.Add(dataSet.table1);
workBook.Worksheets.Add(dataSet.table2);
```

But it was creating two worksheets in the same excel.
Anyone help me how can i do that?

Comment: Incidentally, you should [never use 2 dots with com objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects)

Comment: Alex Can u please suggest me anything more than that how to achieve my requirement?

Comment: I don't know `XLWorkBook` class well enough to answer this but, logically `Worksheets.Add(..)` sounds exactly for adding new worksheets to workbook. I guess you should somehow get the worksheet you want to use first than add the `dataSet.table1-2` to that worksheet.

Answer (score 3):

Try to do the following:

```
workBook.Worksheets.Add(dataSet.table1.Merge(dataSet.table2));
```

It would add 1 worksheet with merged data from the 2 tables.

Comment: Merge is asking for DataRow as its argument.Its not taking the table

Comment: As far as I can see in my VS, argument is DataTable... as I refer your 'dataset' variable of kind "DataSet".
It will be posiible to work with a function that requieres DataRow as well: 
foreach DataRow in table2   
  Merge table 1 with DataRow
And then add worksheet with table 1, containing all data

Comment: Thankyou.Do you have any idea of displaying one table below the another one,instead of merging both the tables?

Comment: Have only one idea not including merging:   
loop on all rows of table1 and write it to the worksheet and then do the same for table2. You can write data directly into a certain row in the worksheet or to certain cell. I think it's less efficient. Merging will probably give you bettr run time.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify cell where should starts table:

```
worksheet.Cell(1, 1).InsertTable(dataTable);
worksheet.Cell(dataTable.Rows.Count + 2, 1).InsertTable(secondTable);
```

More inforamtion about ClosedXML:
https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/wiki/Inserting-Tables